# Mysql add select based on another calculated selected value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want add a property to select statement in mysql query, and that select will depend on the another selected value like,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c, c*5 as a FROM TableName;
```

here `a` will depend on the `c`, but this will return an error saying `Invalid column name 'c'.`

I know this can be handle like `SELECT COUNT(*) as c, COUNT(*)*5 as a FROM TableName;` but my practical case is much complex (this is just a demo).

How can i achieve this more efficiently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `subquery`:

```
Select c*5 as a 
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as c
    From TableName
) x;
```